# Using variables as dict keys in django project settings

Tags: python, django, django-settings

Is it safe and correct to use variables as dict keys in django project `settings.py` ? The chance for the names to be changed is small but it can happen in future.

For example, I have something like that now:

```
EXAMPLE_IDS = {
    'name1': 1,
    'name2': 2,
    'name3': 3,
}
```

I want to change it for something like this so I could use the names independently:

```
EXAMPLE_NAME_1 = 'name1'
EXAMPLE_NAME_2 = 'name2'
EXAMPLE_NAME_3 = 'name3'

EXAMPLE_IDS = {
    EXAMPLE_NAME_1: 1,
    EXAMPLE_NAME_2: 2,
    EXAMPLE_NAME_3: 3,
}
```

Can this change generate any problems with my project in future? Or maybe, is it even better solution?

Comment: Better solution for what? What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Maybe you can define another file called constants.py or something, and mention all these things in this file.

Comment: @Sayse, I want to eliminate a lot of magic strings in the project. Also, I want to use just names seperately in some places. I think this could be a good solution for my needs. I just want to make sure that it is not a bad practice or something that could cause critical errors or something like that.

Comment: That depends, That doesn't sound like those magic strings are *settings*. As said above, a constants file may be a better option.

Comment: Ok, thank you guys. I will consider creating a seperate file for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this change will not generate any problems with your project in future. This is the way you can go forward with.

For a better readability. store these variables in a separate file, say config.py and whenever you need to change anything, you can change it there and will reflect everywhere.

P.S: Don`t forget to import these variables from that file